# Ionic 3 - It is possible to use VirtualScroll to display data from Observable (stream of data)?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, rxjs, ionic3

My current implementation doesn't work.
I'm getting an error but the data is displayed after closing error message. I'm also using ASYNC pipe in [virtualScroll]:

> virtual-scroll.js:591 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

**pages/routes/routes.html**

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="(routesList$ | async )" approxItemHeight="85px">
    <ion-item *virtualItem="let route" (click)="openDetails($event, route)">
     ....
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**pages/routes/routes.ts**

```
export class RoutesPage implements OnInit{

 routesList$: Observable<Route[]>;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
             public navParams: NavParams,
             public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
             public alertCtrl: AlertController,
             private routesProvider: RoutesProvider) {
 }

 ngOnInit() {
     this.routesList$ = this.routesProvider.getRoutesLocal();
 }

 openDetails(event, item) {
     this.navCtrl.push('RouteDetailsPage', {
         route: item
     });
 }
}
```

**providers/routes.ts**

```
getRoutesLocal(): Observable<Route[]> {
    let promise = this.storage.get(this.routesList.storageName).then(res => res);
        return Observable.fromPromise(promise).map(res => JSON.parse(res) );
    }
```

Comment: Have you resolved you issue? I have same issue with virtualScroll.

Comment: Any luck here? I'm stuck at the same problem :(